# How to make load recycler adapter to make it fast

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am loading my recyclerView as showing below:

```
 CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
                HymnsProvider.CONTENT_URI_DETAILS, HymnsProvider.hymn_details_projection,
                HymnsProvider.KEY_LANGUAGE + "='" + language + "'", null, orderBy);
        Cursor dataCursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        List<HymnItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

do {
                //String body = Html.fromHtml(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(HymnsProvider.KEY_BODY)),null,null).toString();
                HymnItem hymnItem = new HymnItem(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(HymnsProvider.KEY_NO)),
                        dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(from)),
                        dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(chorusFrom)),
                        Html.fromHtml(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(HymnsProvider.KEY_BODY)),null,null).toString(),
                        dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(HymnsProvider.KEY_BIBLE_TEXT)),
                        dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(HymnsProvider.KEY_LANGUAGE)));
                itemList.add(hymnItem);
            } while (dataCursor.moveToNext());

myRecyclerView.setAdapter(HymnAdapter(itemList, clickListener, ViewMode));
```

The problem I'm facing is that recylerView loading is very slow because I have 1000 plus rows from database table. After examining it, I discovered the problem is caused by the formatting done with Html.fromHtml().

However, I need to format the html returned from the database because I am using the HymnAdapter to filter. Is there any other way I can load this to make it faster.

I have tried using `replaceAll("<.*?>" , "").replaceAll("&.*?;" , "")` function but it is still slow.

I also try using replace function in sqlite but it does not accept regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pagination to get chunks of records not the whole records. Read this. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Comment: I later use this to load data bit by bit. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to load all items from the database in one go. The point of RecyclerView is to be fast by only showing a "window" into your data set. So you should only be loading / showing items as needed, such that you should only have to use the `fromHtml` method a handful of times as the user scrolls.

Doing a google search for `"recyclerview cursor adapter"` yields many results, the first of which is [this post](https://androidwave.com/implementation-of-recyclerview-with-cursor-adapter/) that demonstrates you could write your adapter in a way that only reads from the database the items it needs.

Hope that helps.